# Try to install SQL Server Express 2016 on Windows Server 2016

Tags: installation, sql

Installation of SQL Server Express 2016 fails on start with this error:

[image]

Log exception:

> (04) 2017-03-28 17:57:02 Downloading manifest from https://download.microsoft.com/download/B/F/2/BF2EDBB8-004D-47F3-AA2B-FEA897591599/Manifest_Bootstrap_All.xml
>
> (04) 2017-03-28 17:57:02 Exception: IsTransientException: False, Message: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.,
>
> (04) 2017-03-28 17:57:02 Exception downloading manifest: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

What's wrong with it and how to fix that?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy by chance?

Comment: Yes, server is behind proxy

Comment: Have you configured this proxy to allow/deny SSL connections in general?  The solution to this problem is to get the ISO for *SQL Server 2016 SP1* and use that instead of the streaming download.

Comment: But there are no iso for express 2016 but only starter that i use. Proxy allow ssl connections

Comment: Just to confirm.  You are trying to upgrade an existing, SQL Server 2016 installation to SQL Server 2016 SP1 installation, right?

Comment: Yes;  There actually is an ISO.  "SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr" will give you an option *to perform an installation or download media only.*  You want to download the installation media.  This should get around your web filtering problem.

Comment: I try to perform clear installation without upgrade.

Comment: Ramhound, could you give me the link to iso? )  I really cannot find this option

Comment: After I start SQLServer2016-SSEI-Expr.exe the first thing that i see is an image in my first post. So I have only log with error (

Comment: Are you downloading the executable from the server itself, or downloading it from another machine, and then running it on the server?

Comment: I tried both scenarios

Answer (score -1):

Eventually ssl was disables by iiscrypto. Thnx to all for help